# Should I be installing my JVM technologies using SDKman or apt-get?

Tags: apt, package-management

My question is about best practices managing a linux environment.

Is it best to be managing software through some 3rd party package manager, or would be better to be using apt-get directly?

What are some of the pros and cons of each approach?

Also, more specifically, there's this tool called [sdkman](http://sdkman.io/index.html) that allows people to manage multiple versions of different JVM related technologies.

Does anyone know how stable/good sdkman is compared to the average PPA for different JVM technologies?

Comment: One of the main issues is security. For a more specific question that hopefully will clarify the security questions around sdkman, see [Installing Kotlin securely, with package signatures, auto-update etc - Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/q/917223/6130)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ubuntu is about using the stable versions of software (at the moment of release of that specific version of Ubuntu).

This means `apt-get` will not install the latest possible version of a specific package. Using a 3rd party installer will (likely) install a newer version of that package. That is the basic difference.

If the 3rd party software is designed well it will install itself outside of the normal install procedure `apt-get` uses and install itself in either `/opt/` or in a user chosen directory (/home/$USER/$software/ for instance). And it should (in theory) also install inside its own directory all the libraries and dependencies needed for it to run.

- `apt-get` (in theory) is more stable than 3rd party.
- 3rd party installer (in theory) is a newer version than `apt-get`.

> Should I be installing my JVM technologies using SDKman or apt-get?

We can't make that decisision for you.